# Better ways to have valuable data indexed, which is ignored currently

Tags: seo, html, search-engines, content, title

```
<a title="">.../a>
```

Hi folks. It seems that my *title tag* which holds extremely valuable and describes contents on my simple design page is currently compeltely denied by search engines and not indexed at all!!

Those descriptions should however be indexed as the describe valuable portions to an otherwise empty page with clean glossary (thats neat and organised to the eye of the viewer. So putting all that descriptive data into visible space would ruin the designish less is more fundamental...

So, which alternatives to the `title` tag do I have, in order to put important contents that are relevant for both user as well as search engines?

```
A    <a name="">......</>
B    <p name="">......</>
C    <a alt="">.......</>
D    <p alt="">.......</>
```

From the above list, arose my question:

> Which of the above is advisable alternative in order to get the valuable actual content indexed? Should it be in a a tag or p tag?

Or are there even better tags for this which still keep layout clean? You suggestions are Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alt tag of images is a very valuable place to put keywords that you are trying to rank for. So that would be

```
<img alt='' src='' />
```

Of the choices that you have, I'd go with A. But to be honest, none of these are going to super great in terms of SEO. Google puts way more emphasis on text that is actually displayed (with the exception of image).

Also be sure that you have meta description in your head. This is really important in your case, since the info is not actually on the page.

```
<meta name="description" content="Description here with keywords">
```

Lastly, if the valuable info contains keywords for ranking you. You can also focus on getting offsite backlinks with those keywords as the anchor text. This is a way to let Google know what the site is about.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree that the alt *attribute* is a valuable place to put keywords. Sure, it probably has *some* value but it's going to be very little especially compared to many of the ranking factors used today. Not to mention you shouldn't be using the alt attribute for SEO purposes anyway. You should be using it for **accessibility** purposes. That attribute exists so people who use screen readers or don't have images enabled in their browsers for any reason  can understand what meaning that image has and the page still makes sense to them. Don't abuse that because you want to please the search engines. That's a losing strategy every time.

Just write your content normally and mark it up properly. If the content is good and your markup is semantic you don't need to abuse HTML attributes to rank better.

If your goal is to get a page indexed or rank better just read any of the [highly voted questions in this site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo?sort=votes&pagesize=50). They contain basic tips that actually matter unlike trying to stuff keywords where they don't belong.

FYI, Google dies not use the meta description in their ranking algorithm. Not even one bit so using that won't affect your rankings.

Comment: Whomever voted this answer down want to explain why? I know I'd be very interested hear what you have to say.

Comment: it wasn't me, but I think we should address the issue that the `title=""` of a link is probably not the best place to put content you want web crawlers to consider relevant, is it?